# Unmarking items in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Whats the quickest way to unmark all the marked items in VC++ 6.0  Ver?

(I just searched for a string, clicked 'Mark All' and then wherever the item appeared, a blue indicator is seen at the left. does anyone know reverting it back?)

I tried project->settings, but in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [DaniWeb question](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/310134/visual-studio-6-ide-question#) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>F2</kbd> should clear them all.

Answer (score 2):

Press Ctrl+F2 to mark/unmark a line of text. Press F2 to skip between marked positions within each source-file. The list of current bookmarks can be displayed by the Edit -> Bookmarks dialog or by pressing ALT+F2. You can clear all bookmarks there.

Answer (score 0):

Clear all bookmarks - `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+L`

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+F2 will clear all bookmarks.